# Android MongoDB Document iteration not consistent, confused

Tags: java, android, mongodb, iteration, mlab

I'm trying to iterate through all my documents and parse the values and add them to their own lists. The thing is when I try to parse and add to the list it stops early half way through to be exact. But when I don't add all the extra code to parse and add to the list it prints out all of them (4).

```
try {
                    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println("Cursor Test" + cursor.next().toJson());

                        myDoc = cursor.next();
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(myDoc.toJson());
                            UserName.add((String) object.get("name"));
                            UserID.add((String) object.get("id"));
                            ProfilePic.add( (String) object.get("ProfilePic"));


                            //System.out.println("USERID:" + UserID);
                            //System.out.println("ProfilePic:" + ProfilePic);
                            //System.out.println("USERNAME:" + UserName);
                            //System.out.println("Count: " + collectionCount);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } finally{cursor.close();}
```

print out only two

while

```
try {
                    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println("Cursor Test" + cursor.next().toJson());

                } finally{cursor.close();}
```

prints out everything as expected

Comment: You are calling `cursor.next()` two times in the first code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example calls cursor.next() twice, advancing the cursor twice per loop. Try just calling it once, as below:

```
try {
  while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    myDoc = cursor.next();
    System.out.println("Cursor Test" + myDoc.toJson());
    try {
      JSONObject object = new JSONObject(myDoc.toJson());
      UserName.add((String) object.get("name"));
      UserID.add((String) object.get("id"));
      ProfilePic.add( (String) object.get("ProfilePic"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
} finally{cursor.close();}
```

Comment: I didn't think the .next moved the cursor. I thought it just pulled the next one. I guess more like a getNext() rather than an actual next.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's how I often think about it: Iterator.getNext()